# Using JS, How Can I integrate bit.ly URL shorten with Twitter @anywhere tweetbox?

Tags: javascript, twitter-anywhere

@anywhere from twitter is a great Javascript only solution.
But it seems I couldn't integrate bitly api with @anywhere tweetbox.

Tweetbox of @anywhere can have default strings to show up in textarea where you can tweet.
I am using bitly api to shorten url right now, but I can't figure out how to pass that shortened url to tweetbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve my problem.

I call bitly api by using jQuery ajax method within the method I call @anywhere api so that I can use the short url.